# How to create a 2d mesh with points on it graphically in Python (Pycharm)?

Tags: python, 2d

I am trying to solve some Reinforcement learning problems. For this I want to get a basic example with a 2D grid (graphically, not just with X's or something) to create an RL task on it. 
I use Pycharm and tried the following code I saw in an online tutorial. But nothing graphically appears on my display when I run it. Can anyone help me with this?

```
from cmath import rect
from tensorflow import fill, size
grid = [ [-1]*8 for n in range(8)]
grid[0][0]=-1
grid [7][7]=-1
w=70
def setup():
  size(800, 600)
def draw():

   x,y = 0,0 #starting position

for row in grid:
    for col in row:
        if col == 1:
            fill(250,0,0)
        else:
            fill(255)
        rect(x,y,w,w)
        x=x+w # move right
    y=y+w  #move down
    x = 0 #rest to left edge
```

Comment: You need to plot something in order to see something, for example `plt.pcolormesh(grid)`. It is unclear what you want and are trying to do.

Comment: there is no plt found in python, did you mean plot?

Comment: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Comment: plot is also not found, I tried to use pyplot and I got that i have no module tkinger, install python3-tk package, but as I wanted to do this via the terminal ti says that the requirements for installing are not fulfilled

Comment: I tried that and still get the error no module named tkinter

Comment: as well it didnt work as I imported tkinter, still the error no module named tkinter

Comment: Then you should first try to solve the import problems by looking for answers on SO.